# How to select related objects in a query in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Coming from django, we have something called select_related that does a join when executing a query such that related objects' data are also fetched.

e.g.

```
# rails + select_related
p = Person.where(job: 1).select_related("job_name")
# so the return query list has objects that 
# can call person.job.job_name without another query
# because selected_related did a join on jobs table
```

How do you do this in rails/activerecord?

Comment: you can do this through associations : link Job and Person models (belongs_to, has_many, whatever suits your requirement) and you can query jobs for a particular person or the other way round.

Comment: while your point is valid, I was looking for a way to optimize the code. Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if you setup associations and call `person.job.job_name` WITHOUT using `includes` (just `Person.where(job:1)`), then each `.job_name` call requires a query to the database.

Comment: I misread your question, thought you're asking for "a" way to do it.  Anyways, using `includes` makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 6):

In rails, it's more common to use `includes` to handle join tables.  It can either do a left outer join (when a where condition needs to reference the joined table) or one more query such as `select * from jobs where id IN (1,3,4,5)`  which solves the n+1 optimization problem.

In your case I would:

```
p = Person.where(job: 1).includes(:jobs)
job = p.job.job_name
```

This does still use two queries, but this is not the use case it is optimized for (and this case doesn't deserve optimization) but if you had a more complicated case it gets better:

```
people = Person.where(status: 'active').includes(:jobs)
people.each {|p| puts p.job.job_name}
```

In this case, it will still only execute 2 queries.

Comment: Is there also a way to select a field on the includes model while doing this whole query?

Comment: Yes, you can use select operator on includes for picking specific columns. Details - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields

Comment: When using select to narrow the fields, it can end up with problems for the resulting object used to represent the results - missing methods on data not returned, and I've had mixed results with methods from attributes not normally in the schema for that object.   It's really not worth the effort to optimize, unless you have benchmarked and profiled your code and *know* that you have a performance problem.  Don't spend time optimizing until you have real data to show what *needs* optimizing.